# List.of(...) or Collections.unmodifiableList()

Tags: java, collections, java-9

If you have a `List<String> strings` instance, would you keep writing:

```
Collections.unmodifiableList(strings)
```

or switch to:

```
List.of(strings.toArray(new String[strings.size()]))
```

What's the initial impact in performance (memory- and runtime-wise) of instantion? Is there a runtime benefit in the `List.of` variant?

Comment: The runtime benefit is with `unmodifiableList` on creation. And if `strings` is an `ArrayList` there is no reason for `List.of`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between List.of and Arrays.asList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46579074/what-is-the-difference-between-list-of-and-arrays-aslist)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72591708/7930516

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is not really a good comparison because these approaches do different things:

- `Collections::unmodifiable...` creates an unmodifiable view. It is *not* immutable because it changes if you're changing the original, backing collection (`list` in your example).
- `...::of` on the other hand, creates an immutable copy. Changing the original list will not affect it.

From a performance view it is obvious that creation of the unmodifiable wrapper is cheaper because it only creates one instance with a single field. The new factory methods will create at least one object, maybe backed by an array (if you have three or more elements), that it needs to copy into.

Access could be faster on the new immutable collections but that would have to be benchmarked.

But correctness trumps performance. What do you *need*? If you need an immutable *copy*, use the new methods (or Guava's `Immutable...`, which I would prefer). If you need *something* immutable, use `unmodifiable...` and throw away the original (and make sure it stays like that). If you need a view that your caller can not edit, use `unmodifiable...`.

Comment: I'd say this is a very logical comparison. How shall one intuitively deduce, that `..::of` creates what you have described here they create and `::unmodifiable...` - what you say they do, in such a granularity? Also, naming of the types or variables *must* be speaking of themselves.. and I really don't know how would one guess, that `List.of(...)` is 1) immutable, and 2) differs from unmodifiable. `ImmutableList.of(..)` would have been much better then. Modification and Mutation are quite ambiguously and overlappingly defined terms in this context. Unmodifiable.. cannot be modified.. mutated..

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri One should not intuitively deduce that - one should read the Javadoc.  What this answer was trying to express: The semantics of the two methods are different, so pick the one with the correct semantics, not the one that may (or may not) be more performant under certain circumstances.

Answer (score 5):

According to [JEP 269 (Convenience Factory Methods for Collections)](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/269):

> **Goals**
>
> *Provide static factory methods on the collection interfaces that will
>   create compact, unmodifiable collection instances.* The API is
>   deliberately kept minimal.
>
> **Non-Goals**
>
> - It is not a goal to provide a fully-general "collection builder"
>     facility that, for example, lets the user control the collection
>     implementation or various characteristics such as mutability, expected
>     size, loading factor, concurrency level, and so forth.
> - *It is not a goal to support high-performance, scalable collections
>     with arbitrary numbers of elements. The focus is on small collections.*
> - It is not a goal to provide unmodifiable collection types. That is,
>     this proposal does not expose the characteristic of unmodifiability in
>     the type system, even though the proposed implementations are actually
>     unmodifiable.
> - It is not a goal to provide "immutable persistent" or "functional"
>     collections.

Comment: Add a synopsis of what you want to express: your point is not entirely clear, though I can guess.

Comment: Are `Collections.unmodifiableXyz` methods build for high-performance? Maybe a JMH test will show the difference. My use-case copes 99% with small lists. That would go conform with the goal of JEP 269.