# Why is `Set.of()` implemented differently from `Collections.emptySet()`?

Tags: java

As far as I can see, the contracts of both are identical. Seems rather pointless to implement a whole new empty set for `Set.of()`.

I would presume the standard library implementors are aware of `Collections.emptySet()`, so there must be a specific reason I am not seeing. Due to the very generic method names, searching in mailing lists is impossible, so I am not sure if this was discussed.

(BTW, it seems `Set.of()` just uses a `SetN` with an empty input array, so it will probably be less efficient than `emptySet()` as well.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46404933/map-of-vs-collections-emptymap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a single difference "code-wise", that I am aware of.

```
Collections.emptySet().contains(null); // false
Set.of().contains(null); // NullPointerException
```

So they are not inter-changeable.

Comment: Also the serial form is different - if you care about interoperating through e.g. JMX with older VMs.

Answer (score 2):

`Set.of()` uses a nice clean helper from `ImmutableCollections` which was introduced with Java 9.

`Collections` on the other hand was says `since 1.2`, and was only "adapted" to generics and such things over time.

So:

- the `Collections` implementation is historically grown, and you would probably not be doing it like that any more today
- so, when introducing the functionality in a new context, you do it in a different way.

And more importantly: all the `of` methods within `Set` are just delegating to [ImmutableCollections](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ImmutableCollections.java). And then it makes no sense that `of()` would be implemented in a completely different way than all the other `of(x)` methods.