# I am trying to return an empty list

Tags: java, list, oop, if-statement, arraylist

I'm new to list, but I'm trying to return an empty list through a method, so that list can be used somewhere else. But I don't know how to do it.

```
public List<Something> login (String user, String key){
    if (success) {
        System.out.println("Welcome");
        return  (THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO RETURN AN EMPTY LIST);
    } 

    System.out.println("Incorrect Information");
        return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you not just create the `List` wherever you need it instead of returning an empty one here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72591708/7930516

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.util.List` is an interface and therefore you cannot instantiate one.

You should instantiate one of it's implementation classes and return that object.

Like `return new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Yes but it looks like he tried to do `return new List();` and the IDE doesn't let him do that; causing some confusion :)

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to use it somewhere else, you can return any implementation of `List` interface. The most used:

```
new ArrayList<>();
```

Also there are a few ways to return an immutable empty list (means that you can not modify it):

```
return Collections.emptyList();
return List.of();  // from java9
```

See difference between them [List.of() or Collections.emptyList()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39400238/list-of-or-collections-emptylist)

Also see more about [List implementations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/list.html)

Comment: Worth noting emptyList() and of() returns two different types of List (they're a bit different in the implementation).

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
return new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: could you explain please

Comment: Nothing to explain, really. We're instantiating an empty list and returning it.